# Use an inline visualforce peage with standard page layouts

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

VisualForce Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="OpportunitySearchController">  
    <style type="text/css">
        body {background: #F3F3EC; padding-top: 15px}
    </style>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Search for Opportunities by Keyword" id="block" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageMessages />

            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel for="searchText">Keyword</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:panelGroup >
                    <apex:inputText id="searchText" value="{!searchText}"/>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search}" rerender="resultsBlock" status="status"/>
                    </apex:panelGroup>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:actionStatus id="status" startText="Searching... please wait..."/>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="resultsBlock" columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!searchResults}" var="o" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(searchResults))}">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!o.Id}">{!o.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!o.StageName}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!o.Amount}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!o.CloseDate}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Code:

public class OpportunitySearchController {
    //added an instance varaible for the standard controller
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
    // the actual account
    private Account a;
    // the results from the search. do not init the results or a blank rows show up initially on page load
    public List searchResults {get;set;}

```
// the text in the search box
public string searchText {
    get {
        if (searchText == null) searchText = 'Acme'; // prefill the serach box for ease of use
        return searchText;
    }
    set;
}

public OpportunitySearchController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    //initialize the stanrdard controller
    this.controller = controller;
    this.a = (Account)controller.getRecord();

}

// fired when the search button is clicked
public PageReference search() {
    if (searchResults == null) {
        searchResults = new List<opportunity>(); // init the list if it is null
    } else {
        searchResults.clear(); // clear out the current results if they exist
    }
    // Note: you could have achieved the same results as above by just using:
    // searchResults = new List<categoryWrapper>();

    // use some dynamic soql to find the related opportunities by name
 String qry = 'Select o.Id, o.Name, o.StageName, o.CloseDate, o.Amount from Opportunity o Where AccountId = \'' +a.Id+ '\' And o.Name LIKE \'%'+searchText+'%\' Order By o.Name';
    searchResults = Database.query(qry);
    return null;
}
```

}
error:Visualforce Error
Help for this Page

System.QueryException: invalid ID field: null
Error is in expression '{!search}' in component  in page accountsearch: Class.OpportunitySearchController.search: line 39, column 1

Class.OpportunitySearchController.search: line 39, column 1

Comment: You did not escape you quotes with a \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing backslash in your SOQL where you are trying to create it using string. Please try the below query instead of your line, and try to save.

```
String qry = 'Select o.Id, o.Name, o.StageName, o.CloseDate, o.Amount from Opportunity o Where AccountId = \'' +a.Id+ '\' And o.Name LIKE \'%'+searchText+'%\' Order By o.Name';
```

Comment: Visualforce Error
Help for this Page

System.QueryException: invalid ID field: null
Error is in expression '{!search}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page accountsearch: Class.OpportunitySearchController.search: line 39, column 1

Class.OpportunitySearchController.search: line 39, column 1

Comment: Can you please post your latest code, where you are facing the issue.

Comment: I Posted the latest code Please help me @Nitish Singhal

Comment: Hi, why do you need to include the a.id in the query. You are developing a search functionality, and I don't think any id will be available before search. So, please remove the search criteria of Id from your query.